npm Install gives dependency conflict
After adding @ng-select/ng-select, I am getting dependency errors when building the project.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @swimlane/ngx-datatable@19.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"14.3.0" from @angular/forms@14.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"<15.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@9.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm ERR!       @ng-select/ng-select@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"14.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"14.3.0" from @angular/platform-browser@14.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.3.0" from @angular/forms@14.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@"<15.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@9.1.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm ERR!         @ng-select/ng-select@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.3.0" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"14.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     4 more (@angular/router, ngx-select-ex, ngx-toastr, the root project)
npm ERR!   12 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.0.2" from @swimlane/ngx-datatable@19.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable
npm ERR!   @swimlane/ngx-datatable@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.2" from @swimlane/ngx-datatable@19.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable
npm ERR!     @swimlane/ngx-datatable@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

**These are the packages
**
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.3.0",

    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",

 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.13",

I've already tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and run nmp i, nothing works.
I've tried --force and legacy-peer-deps.
